# Remove focus outline TideSDK

Tags: javascript, html, css, tidesdk

When I press a button in my TideSDK App, I get an ugly focus outline. Is there any way to disable/remove this? I've tried setting outline to none, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

```
:focus, :active {
    outline: none;
    border: 0;
}
```

Here's a picture of the outline in question:

[image: ugly outline]

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove it from all links:

```
a {
   outline: 0;
}
```

More in-depth explanation here: http://css-tricks.com/removing-the-dotted-outline/